Sybase IQ 16.1 OLEDB driver problem with SQL Server Integration Services / Visual Studio
I have identified a critical issue with the latest OLEDB Sybase IQ driver. The issue occurs intermittently and does not follow a predictable pattern.
I am using OLEDB driver in our Visual Studio Data projects (SQL Server Integration Services - SSIS) to execute Sybase IQ stored procedures or transfer data from Sybase IQ as the source to destination tables (SQL Server).
The issue occurs during debugging of the VS project or when running via SQL Server Agent (job):

Sometimes, the task using Sybase IQ connection finishes successfully, but no data is processed, or the procedure is not executed
One part of SSIS workflow is processed, but the subsequent steps are skipped, and the workflow pretends everything is done
Running jobs fail due to a problem with Sybase IQ driver

Can anyone help solve this issue? Thanks.
Microsoft and SAP support have already been informed, but with no success.
System information:

Sybase IQ Database Version: SAP IQ/16.1.040.2016/17091/P/SP04.14/MS/Windows 2012 R2/64bit
Sybase IQ Driver: dboledb17.dll (ver. 17.0.11.2690)
Operating System: Windows Server 2022 Standard ver. 21H2 build 20348.2655 (where SQL Server and Visual Studio run)
Microsoft Visual Studio: Professional 2022 64bit ver. 17.10.4 (.NET Framework 4.8.09037)
Microsoft SQL Server: Developer 64bit (ver. 16.0.1125.1)

